# Deleting all until you find capital letter in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have an output

```
timeout.o:
                 U alarm
000000000000t000 T catch_sig_alarm
0000000000000b13 T set_timeout
                 U signal
0000000g00000000 B timeout
```

and I need to get rid of the numers and letters before T and U and B so output will be like this:

```
timeout.o:
U alarm
T catch_sig_alarm
T set_timeout
U signal
B timeout
```

How can I do that using sed? I tried something like `sed 's/[0-9]*//;s/ *//'` but I dont know how to say to delete the letters too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

Based on the real input data (I thought `timeout.o` was the file name):

```
... | awk 'NF>1 {sub("^[^A-Z]*","")} {print}'
timeout.o:
U alarm
T catch_sig_alarm
T set_timeout
U signal
B timeout
```

It does the substitution just in case the line contains more than one field. This way, the first line is skipped. It would be the same in this case to do `NR>1`.

---

You can use this:

```
$ sed 's/^[^A-Z]*//' timeout.o
U alarm
T catch_sig_alarm
T set_timeout
U signal
B timeout
```

What it does is to fetch all the characters from the beginning (`^` indicates beginning of the line) not being a capital letter (`[^A-Z]*` means that) and replacing them with an empty string.

Note the expression `sed 's/hello/bye/'` replaces once `hello` with `bye`. If you want to do multiple substitution (is not this case), you can do `sed 's/hello/bye/g'`.

If you want to do an in-place substitution, do `sed -i ...`.

Comment: Problem of sed 's/^[^A-Z]*//' is that it delete even the timeout.o which I need after subtitution. I know the header of this question is bad, sadly I realized it now that timeout.o is without cappital letters. –

Comment: Oh, so `timeout.o` is also in your output? If so, my fault as I did edit your question thinking it was the name of the file.

Comment: it is :) and it depends on the name of the function (so it can be anything.o )

Comment: The `awk` solution is nice. Much more concise and understandable than my pure-`sed` one.

Answer (score 2):

```
input | sed '/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]\+\.[a-z]\+:$/!s/^[^A-Z]*//'
```

Explanation: `[^A-Z]` is everything *not* uppercase letter. The first `^` makes sure, the expression starts at line beginning and doesn't go rogue in the middle of the line. The expression simply starts deleting everything in a line, until it finds an uppercase letter.

The first part `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]\+\.[a-z]\+:$/!` up until the `s` constricts the removal to all lines, that do not (the final `!`) match exactly `[letter]...[a dot][letter]...[a colon]`, which looks like a filename production.

Comment: Problem of sed 's/^[^A-Z]*//' is that it delete even the timeout.o which I need after subtitution. I know the header of this question is bad, sadly I realized it now that timeout.o is without cappital letters.

Comment: Hey sorry I did an improper edition. `timeout.o` is part of the input. See current version of the question.

Comment: Alright. You can go with @fedorqui's answer, but I'll try to craft a pure sed solution, too.

Comment: You did such a regex! Note the answer by @djjolem covers it by adding a space after the `[0-9a-z]*`.

Comment: Thanks, but the space is covered by `[^A-Z]` and will be deleted, too, if before the uppercase letter. The other one is for filename detection.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat timeout.o | sed 's/^[^BUT]* //'
```

Or

```
sed 's/[0-9a-z]* //;s/ *//'
```

Comment: Hey sorry I did an improper edition. `timeout.o` is part of the input. See current version of the question.

Comment: Oh that's a good way! This way the first line is not matched, I like it.

Comment: Note also that `cat timeout.o | sed 's/^[^BUT]* //'` can be written as `sed 's/^[^BUT]* //' timeout.o`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the first column seems to have a fixed width, I'd just use

```
{ read; echo "$REPLY"; cut -c18-; } < timeout.o
```

to remove the first 17 characters (while preserving the initial line in full).

Comment: thx for answer, the question is now edited so it is clear that timeout.o is not a file but a part of the string